# Finding conditional expectation from system of equations

Tags: statistics, conditional-expectation

I have three equations:

$$X_m = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \cdot X_I + \varepsilon_{BL}$$

$$W_M = X_M + \varepsilon_{MBL}$$

$$W_I = \gamma_0 + \gamma_1 \cdot X_I + \varepsilon_{RDI}$$

The $\varepsilon$'s are normally distributed with mean 0, variance $\sigma^2$.

I need to find E[$X_I\mid W_I$] and E[$X_I\mid W_I,W_M$]. The first is straightforward because I have an equation that relates $X_I$ and $W_I$, but how do find the latter expectation?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a serious error in your reasoning.  You say "The first is straightforward because I have an equation that relates $X_I$ and $W_I$".  The equation implies that $\operatorname{E}(W_I\mid X_I)=\gamma_0+\gamma_1 X_I$.

But you need $\operatorname{E}(X_I\mid W_I)$.  You haven't given enough information to find that.  It may be tempting to say that if $W_I=\gamma_0+\gamma_1 X_I$ then $X_I=(W_I-\gamma_0)/\gamma_1$ and then think that that gives you the expected value.  But that is wrong except when the correlation is $1$ or $-1$.  For example, suppose one has $\operatorname{E}(W\mid X)=X$ and the correlation between $W$ and $X$ is $0.01$.  Then $\operatorname{E}(X\mid W) = 0.0001 W$.  You have not told us the correlations.

Comment: Sorry, I seem to be missing something - could you explain that intermediate step with the correlation in further detail or point me to a resource that explains this property? And if I had all the necessary correlation calculations, how would I find E($X_I|W_I,W_M$)?

Comment: If $(X,Y)$ has a bivariate normal distribution, with means $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$, variances $\sigma_X^2$ and $\sigma_Y^2$ and correlation $\rho$ (so that the covariance is $\rho\sigma_X\sigma_Y$), then $\displaystyle\operatorname{E}(X\mid Y) = \mu_X + \rho\sigma_X\left(\frac{Y-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y}\right)$.  That's how you get a conditional expected value in this situation. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thank you so much! Just one more point of clarification. Would I use E(W|X) to estimate $\mu_W$ in this case?